# Последний столбец на оставшиюся ширину без calc() и фикс. размеров

Tags: html, css

В таблице у меня 2 столбца. Как сделать, что бы второй столбец занимал всю ширину, при этом давая всё место первому для всего контента?

```html
<table class="range"> 
    <tr><td>от:</td><td><input type="number"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>до:</td><td><input type="number"></td></tr>
</table>
```

В интернете вижу только решения с фикс шириной и с calc().

Comment: возникает резонный вопрос, а зачем тебе тогда вообще второй стобец, если его задача отдавать весь свой размер 1му столбцу, не проще ли тогда просто сделать один и дать ему `width: 100%`?

Answer (score 0):

Первому столбцу задаешь ширину в 0 пикселей, второму не задаешь. Второй будет автоматически занимать все оставшееся место.
Контент в первом столбце в любом случае разопрет его до минимально необходимого размера, ужав, разумеется, второй столбец.